# How to mention a long theorem in a presentation/beamer

Tags: presentation

I have to do a short presentation using beamer for 25 minutes about a topic.
In the presentation i want to discuss the following proposition with a lot of conditions

> **Proposition 2.8.5.8.**  Let $\mathscr{C}$ be a monoidal $\infty$-category.  Assume that $\mathscr{C}$ admits geometric realizations of simplicial objects and that the tensor product $\mathscr{C}\times\mathscr{C}\to\mathscr{C}$ preserves geometric realizations.  Let $\mathscr{M}$ be an $\infty$-category left-tensored over $\mathscr{C}$ and let $M \in \mathscr{M}$ be an object.  There exists an algebra object $A \in \operatorname{Alg}(\mathscr{C})$ and an equivalence $\operatorname{RMod}_{A}(\mathscr{C}) \simeq \mathscr{M}$ of $\infty$-categories left-tensored over $\mathscr{C}$ which carries $A$ to $M$ if and only if the following conditions are satisfied:
>
> 1. The $\infty$-category $\mathscr{M}$ admits geometric realizations of simplicial objects.
> 2. The action map $\mathscr{C}\times\mathscr{M} \to \mathscr{M}$ preserves geometric realizations of simplicial objects.
> 3. The function $F:\mathscr{C}\to\mathscr{M}$ given by $F(C)=C\otimes M$ admits a right adjoint $G$.
> 4. The functor $G$ preserves geometric realizations of simplicial objects.
> 5. The functor $G$ is conservative.
> 6. For every object $N\in\mathscr{M}$ and every object $C\in\mathscr{C}$, the evident map
>    $$ F(C\otimes G(N)) \simeq C\otimes G(N)\otimes M \simeq C\otimes FG(N) \to C\otimes N $$
>    is adjoint to an equivalence $C \otimes G(N) \to G(C\otimes N)$.

I am not sure if it is better to write out the proposition in full, or instead just write "satisfying some conditions". Either way i would appreciate some advice

Edit:
To give some further context: this is for a purpose of an interview, so the audience are expected to know the background of the topic well. I do not expect the audience to know the proposition beforehand, but that they have seen similar results, and will find it reasonable if they read the statement.

I use the proposition on a specific case which satisfies the criteria to show two objects are the same, which is a vital part of the presentation. The focus on the talk is not on the criteria however.

I would say conditions (1),(2),(4) are not very meaningful while (3),(5) are meaningful enough for me to mention, and (6) somewhere in between.

Comment: The main rule is not to put more than seven lines on a slide. So you might split your text over two slides.

Comment: To someone knowledgeable about this topic: are all these conditions obviously necessary or all obviously sufficient?  Or are there some that are more surprising?  Are some conditions more important than others?  Are some of the conditions merely to rule out weird or trivial counterexamples and not otherwise meaningful?  The point is that we can't answer your question without an understanding of these conditions rather than purely formal knowledge of them.  We also need to know how this proposition fits in the rest of the talk - how you use it.

Comment: It's worth asking if you need to include (what looks like) a technical lemma into your talk at all. "See our paper" is a fine response in a short talk. If it can't be properly understood while the slide is on the screen, it won't be.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it seems more appropriate to some other SE site, as it does not seem to be about teaching mathematics.

Comment: @Tommi I'll let the wisdom of the crowd prevail, but I think that "giving a talk on a mathematical topic" falls within the remit of "teaching", since talks are supposed to be pedagogical.  Though if you have a *specific* suggestion about where this would be more on-topic, I'm all ears (as a moderator on Math SE, I don't think it would be on-topic there).

Comment: I don't think this question can be answered as it stands. Who is the audience? Do they know this 'proposition' well? How vital is it for understanding the rest of your talk?

Comment: @Dominique I know that is the general advice, and I am generally on-board for it, but I do think that there are times that it can be safely violated, particularly if one is trying to create slides which will be used in a presentation *and* later made available for others to look over.  In my own talks, I treat technical results as something like "figures":  I put it up on the screen, note that it is technical, point out the highlights, and quickly move on.

Comment: @XanderHenderson, Academia SX might be a better fit if it's about presenting in an academic context as opposed to teaching.

Comment: @Dominique: Independently of the merits of this "main rule" (which are more than questionable), OP should most certainly not split the statement of a single proposition over two slides. If they do this, they are going to loose everybody in the audience as soon as they switch to the second slide. It's an extremely common problem in mathematical talks that the speaker overestimates the short term memory of their audience by several orders of magnitudes.

Comment: I share some of the concerns here whether this is really on-topic. Yet, I think @XanderHenderson has an important point in saying that talks are supposed to be pedagogical - and from experience, this specific point seems to be so widely ignored in many math talks that I chose to ignore my concerns and to post an answer instead.

Comment: @jochen: if a piece of informtion is so important, the author needs to find a solution to keep it visible while showing the next slide.

Comment: For what it is worth, I have discussed this question with moderators on Academia---it would be considered off-topic there without more details.  It would also be off-topic on Math.  If there *is* an SE site where this would be on-topic, it is here (the community here is free to make its choice).

Comment: @XanderHenderson, maybe, just maybe it would be acceptable on Math Overflow. Either that or still Academia, given the edit giving context that it's for an interview.

Comment: @JW The Academia mods saw this version of the question, and didn't want it.  MO doesn't want it, either.  *If* this question is on-topic anywhere on the network, it is here.  I will not be migrating it elsewhere.  If the community here *also* feels that it is off-topic, so be it---not every question has a home on the SE network.

Comment: @XanderHenderson, thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 12):

Alright, I hope you don't mind if I'm a bit blunt. Given the information in the post we can't know for sure, of course, but it seems unlikely that what you are planning to do will work well.

- You say you want *"use the proposition on a specific case which satisfies the criteria to show two objects are the same"*.

  How are you going to do this in practice? As your question indicates, you have noted that even the proposition itself hardly fits on a slide. As soon as the slide with the proposition is gone, nobody in the audience will remember the details of the proposition. The precise setting of the proposition, the mathematical objects and structures that occur in the proposition, the assumptions, the six conditions - almost all of it will be gone at the very moment you switch the slide.

  If you're skeptical, you can test this yourself: ask a friend or colleague who's similarly familiar with the topic as the expected audience to assist you with the following little experiment: Show and explain them the slide with the proposition in the same way as you would to it with your audience, then do the same with the next slide - then stop and ask them to recall all of the proposition that they remember. I promise it will be heart-breaking.

  I can see one potential way, though, how to make this work: After discussing the proposition (slowly and in detail), you could proceed as follows: on the next slide, copy only the first part of the proposition without the conditions (1)-(6), then add the situation where you want to use the proposition and make sure that there is still sufficient space left at the bottom of the slide. Then go through the conditions (1)-(6) step by step in the following way: always leave the upper two parts of the slide the same, show one of the conditions (1)-(6) (but not the others!), and explain (slowly!) why this condition is satisfied here. Give the audience time to digest, then replace the condition with the next one and iterate.

  This is something that *can* work if you do it really well and if you take enough time to do it. It will, however, use up most of your 25 minutes. For a job interview I would certainly not recommend it, though (even less if you don't have practice in doing this kind of thing in other talks where the stakes are lower). In any case, this strategy only makes sense if showing the application of this proposition is the main point of your talk.
- Regarding *"I use the proposition on a specific case which satisfies the criteria to show two objects are the same, which is a vital part of the presentation. The focus on the talk is not on the criteria however"*:

  While I don't know any details of your planned talk, those two sentences make me worried that you are heavily overestimating how much you can do in 25 minutes. This is a very common problem with mathematical talks: Many mathematicians seem, for reasons that are beyond me, unable or unwilling to apply basic arithmetic when planning a talk. So here's the arithmetic for your proposition:

  I read out the proposition loud and clearly and measured the time: it took me about 1 minute and 45 seconds - just for reading it aloud, without any explanations or context, without rhetoric pauses, without any rephrasing, without using any additional measures that would give the audience time to think and to process what is being discussed. From experience I can say that adding all those things to reach at least an acceptable level of comprehensibility will more than double the required time - so you'll need at least about four minutes for this single slide (and this is really the minimum - I'd personally plan more time than that for such a slide). So for a 25 minute talk you can, at the very most, have six times the content that is in the proposition (assuming that you want the audience to have a serious chance of really understanding what you are talking about). If this fits with your plan, you might be fine. If not, it shows a problem that you need to solve before giving your talk.
- You also write *"this is for a purpose of an interview, so the audience are expected to know the background of the topic well."*

  I obviously don't know your audience, so please take the following with a grain of salt. But another very common mistake in mathematical talks is that the speaker heavily overestimates how familiar the audience is with (the foundations of) the material in the talk. To a certain degree, this even seems to remain true if one is aware of this fact and tries to compensate for it. (I'd say that I'm personally very well aware of this problem, and still I regularly happen to fall prey to this bias.)

  In the end, it's you who knows the precise context of the talk, but just to be on the safe side, I'd suggest that you reconsider why you assume that the fact that this is for an interview implies that the audience knows the background well. Do you know who precisely is in the audience? And do you know that their field is really so close to yours that they know all the things well which you assume they know well?

I hope this is of some help to you. Best of luck for your interview!

Comment: Thank you for your detailed response! Given yours and others feedback, i plan to just mention that these objects are isomorphic, without going in to detail how it works.

Also thank you for your advice about time management and expectations on the knowledge of the audience. I will keep this in mind for the rest of the presentation.

Comment: *"As soon as the slide with the proposition is gone, nobody in the audience will remember the details of the proposition. "* Unless they take accurate notes, that is. I usually do and it occasionally frustrates the presenter to the extreme when I say: "Wait! I cannot follow that fast. Keep this slide on the screen for a few minutes!". But I'm happy that somebody sees the problem here and explains it clearer than I could possibly do. +1.

Comment: @fedja: I have to admit, I really don't understand the psychosocial mechanism that causes those "rush through slides like a rollercoaster" talks to be so widespread. I belong to the dying species of those who prefer to give blackboard talks at conferences and seminars. Whenever I do so, some people will explain to me that they are happy that at least somebody gives a blackboard talk, since they find blackboard talks much easier to follow - but almost none of them will give a blackboard talk themselves. [...]

Comment: [...] When I have to use slides (i.e., when there is no acceptable blackboard available), one can literally feel some people's disbelieve when they see that I have prepared only 5 or 6 slides for 30 minutes - and afterwards, some of them will tell me that this was finally a talk that was slow enough such that they could understand a significant part of the contents. But at the next opportunity the very same people will, when giving their own talk, present at least three or four times as much material within the same time frame. It's really a mystery for me.

Answer (score 7):

As others have speculated/commented, attempting explicit enunciation of such a  long "proposition" is almost never the right thing to do, apart from formatting issues: the people who already know it more-or-less are not enlightened, and people who've never seen it before will definitely not assimilate it in a minute or two and be ready to use it.

(I do understand the impulse to "explain" how technicalities work out just right... but sometimes it just doesn't fit... I've had my share of ghastly failures in such regard, and never had a good feeling about it.)

I'd try thinking of a *qualitative* (and shorter) description, even if imprecise, of what that proposition asserts, ... and how happy/fortunate that is for your larger story.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I think i will try and see if i can make a intuitive argument of why the two objects are the same, and if that is not possible just assert that they are the same.